# TkInter GUI interface for STM32 MCU

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

I'm very new to Python and this is my first ever Python GUI app.  I am writing a little app to interact with my STM32 Black Pill board.  This is very minimal as I intend to use this as the basis for future project with specific intentions.  How did I do? What can I do better?

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial.tools.list_ports
from threading import *

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("Breadboard MCU Interface")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        ### Menu Configuration ###############################################################################
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.configmenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.configmenu.add_command(label="Communications Port", command=lambda: PortConfig())
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Configure", menu=self.configmenu)

        self.menubar.add_command(label="Connect", command=connect)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)
        ### End Menu Configuration ###########################################################################

        ### GPIO Canvas ######################################################################################
        self.gpio_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=325, height=100)
        self.gpio_canvas.create_text(170, 30, text="GPIO", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))
        self.gpio_canvas.create_text(25, 55, text="Port A")
        self.gpio_canvas.create_text(25, 70, text="Port B")

        self.ports = { "A": [], "B": [] }
        for pin in range(16, 0, -1):
            self.ports['A'].append(self.gpio_canvas.create_oval(60 + (pin * 15), 50, 70 + (pin * 15), 60, fill = "green"))
            self.ports['B'].append(self.gpio_canvas.create_oval(60 + (pin * 15), 65, 70 + (pin * 15), 75, fill = "green"))

        self.gpio_canvas.pack(fill="both")
        ### End GPIO Canvas ###################################################################################

    def updatePinDisplay(self, portid, pinvalues):
        for i in range(0,16):
            pinvalue = ((pinvalues >> i) & 1)
            if pinvalue:
                self.gpio_canvas.itemconfig(self.ports[portid][i], fill="green2")
            else:
                self.gpio_canvas.itemconfig(self.ports[portid][i], fill="green")
        #self.update()

class PortConfig(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def getSelection(choice):
            self.selected = str(choice).split(' ')[0]

        def setComPort():
            global comport
            comport = self.selected
            connect()
            self.destroy()

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Connection Configuration")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.config(padx=5, pady=5)

        ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        default = tk.StringVar(self, "Please select a communications port")

        self.selected = None
        self.portslist = tk.OptionMenu(self, default, *ports, command=getSelection).pack(side="left")
        self.okbutton = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=setComPort).pack(side="left", padx=10)

        self.focus()
        self.grab_set()

class WorkThread(Thread):
    global connection

    def run(self):
        global porta_pins

        print("Worker thread running...")
        try:
            while connection.is_open:
                while connection.in_waiting:
                    indata = connection.readline().decode('Ascii')
                    portid, pinvalues = indata.split('#')
                    app.updatePinDisplay(portid, int(pinvalues))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            pass
            
        print("Worker thread closing down.")

def connect():
    global connection, connected, workthread

    try:
        connection = serial.Serial(comport, baudrate=1152000, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=2)
    except:
        pass

    if connection is not None:
        connected = True
        connection.write("Connection established.\r\n".encode('Ascii'))
        app.menubar.entryconfigure(2, label="Disconnect", command=disconnect)
        workthread = WorkThread()
        workthread.start()
    else:
        connected = False
        print("Connection failed.")

def disconnect():
    global connection, connected, workthread

    connection.close()
    connected = False
    workthread.join()
    workthread = None
    app.menubar.entryconfigure(2, label="Connect", command=connect)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    comport = None
    connection = None
    connected = False
    workthread = None

    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. I have rolled back your edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is some pretty nice code; it's clear what is happening here.

---

## use informative names

```
from threading import *

class Main(tk.Tk):
```

That's a bit generic.
Consider using something more descriptive, perhaps:

```
class BlackPillGui(tk.Tk):
```

And that `*` star is just annoying.
Please prefer `from threading import Thread`.

---

## globals?!?

```
    global connection, connected, workthread

    connection.close()
```

Two concerns here.

1. Prefer to put these in an object or datastructure, instead of using the global namespace.
2. No need to declare `global connection` since you don't assign to it. The subsequent undeclared `app` reference offers an illustration of such use.

---

## don't represent the same concept two ways

I am sad to see the `connected` boolean being introduced.

It appears it is always identical to `if connection is not None:`,
or just `if connection:`.
Recommend you elide it.

Kudos on using an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard.
Though frankly, since everything relies on Tk,
it's not like a unit test could import this module
and usefully test it.

---

## restraint in comments

```
        ### Menu Configuration ###############################################################################
```

Uggh, ASCII art!

If there's some coding standard which requires this,
that you're trying to adhere to,
then cite the reference.

Otherwise, [pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#block-comments)
asks that you show some restraint. In particular, when you lint
your code you are apparently inhibiting E266 messages in your `.flake8`
config file: `E266 too many leading '#' for block comment`

---

## layout, magic numbers

The GPIO canvas has a bunch of
[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
for layout, with relationships among some of them.

```
        self.gpio_canvas.create_text(25, 55, text="Port A")
        self.gpio_canvas.create_text(25, 70, text="Port B")
```

IDK, maybe that's OK?
Consider defining things like `LEFT_MARGIN = 25`.

---

## comments suggest helpers

The fact that you felt it necessary to point out the
begin / end of Menu Configuration, and of GPIO Canvas,
suggests that the `__init__` ctor should have a
pair of helpers:

```
    def menu_config(self):
        ...
    def gpio_canvas(self):
        ...
```

---

## use conventional names

```
    def updatePinDisplay(self, portid, pinvalues):
```

Pep8 asks that you spell it `update_pin_display`.

Pleaseconsiderclarifyingcertainnames such as `com_port`, `ok_button`,
`port_id`, and `pin_values`.

---

## optional type hints to help the reader

The plural pin values name was very helpful, thank you.
And the "right shift `i` places" soon clarifies things.
Still, when I read the signature I had in mind there
was a **container** of values, rather than a bit vector
encoded as an `int`.

Declaring

```
    ...(self, port_id: str, pin_values: int):
```

would be a kindness to the Gentle Reader.
(Plus, `mypy` could help with linting it if you like.)

---

## mapping for business logic

```
        if pinvalue:
            self.gpio_canvas.itemconfig(self.ports[portid][i], fill="green2")
        else:
            self.gpio_canvas.itemconfig(self.ports[portid][i], fill="green")
```

You can [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up
the pin coloring in this way:

```
        pin_colors = ["green", "green2"]
        self.gpio_canvas.itemconfig(self.ports[port_id][i], fill=pin_colors[pin_value])
```

This avoids pasting a pair of similar calls to `itemconfig`.

---

## simplify nested loops

```
            while connection.is_open:
                while connection.in_waiting:
```

Recommend a simple conjunct:

```
            while (connection.is_open:
                and connection.in_waiting):
```

I worry a little about failure modes, and the UX.
I imagine there may be off-nominal situations where we loop forever,
not obtaining any text lines.
Maybe it would be useful to `print()` or to update a Tk text box,
letting the user know we're awaiting input?
And then immediately blank it out, once the input is received.

---

## no bare excepts

```
def connect():
    ...
    except:
        pass
```

Disabling CTRL/C `KeyboardInterrupt` is *not* what you want.
Prefer `except Exception:`

Also, you could simplify `print(str(e))`
to the identical `print(e)`.

---

This code is clear, and achieves its design objectives.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on this codebase.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, I appreciate your response and will work on following these suggestions moving forward.